# Azure Logic App: Filter array with multiple conditions

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am using filter array method to get list of blobs which are added within last 5 minutes (Last modified is less than 5 min) and if blob display name contains specific test(word `Test` in my case).

My logic:
[image]

I am using below condition for filtering array

```
@and(less(item()?['LastModified'], addMinutes(utcNow(), -5)), contains(item()?['DisplayName'], 'Test'))
```

But `contains(item()?['DisplayName'], 'Test')` only working, last modified is getting ignored.

How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> blobs which are added within last 5 minutes

Change `less(item()?['LastModified'], addMinutes(utcNow(), -5))` to `greater(item()?['LastModified'], addMinutes(utcNow(), -5))`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my condition this will be helping you.
List of users who belongs to US country and department belin

```
@equals(and(equals(item()?['Country_Code'], 'US'), or(equals(item()?['Department'], 'Dept1'), equals(item()?['Department'], 'Dept2'))), true)
```